# WritableBitmap to RandomAccessStreamReference

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, writablebitmap

i have next question:

I have made a screenshot using WinRT XAML Toolkit (code1)

Now i want to attach this WritableBitmap to email (code2)

**CODE 1**

```
WriteableBitmap wb = null;
            var start = DateTime.Now;
            const int count = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                wb = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(this);
            }
            var end = DateTime.Now;
            var duration = end - start;
            var renderInS = duration.TotalMilliseconds / count;
            if (renderInS > 0)
            {
                test.Source = wb;
                // HERE MUST BE CODE INCLUDED
            }
```

**CODE 2**

```
DataPackage requestData = request.Data;
            requestData.Properties.Title = TitleInputBox.Text;
            requestData.Properties.Description = DescriptionInputBox.Text; // The description is optional.

            // It's recommended to use both SetBitmap and SetStorageItems for sharing a single image
            // since the target app may only support one or the other.

            List<IStorageItem> imageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
            imageItems.Add(this.imageFile);
            requestData.SetStorageItems(imageItems);

            RandomAccessStreamReference imageStreamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(this.imageFile);
            requestData.Properties.Thumbnail = imageStreamRef;
            requestData.SetBitmap(imageStreamRef);
            succeeded = true;
```

This means i need to firstly save image to local storage, and then read it and attach it.

**The question:**

**1) How to save WritableBitmap to applications local storage?**

**2) Maybe there is a way not to save image to attach it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

One more way using [`WriteableBitmapEx`](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) & [`MemoryRandomAccessStream`](http://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/)

```csharp
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(MyWriteableBitmap.ToByteArray());
var randomAccessStream = new MemoryRandomAccessStream(stream);
DataPackage requestData = args.Request.Data;
RandomAccessStreamReference imageStreamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(randomAccessStream);
```

---

Try this to save WriteableBitmap To StorageFile

```csharp
private async Task<StorageFile> WriteableBitmapToStorageFile(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
{
    var picker = new FileSavePicker();
    picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG Image", new string[] { ".jpg" });
    StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (file != null && writeableBitmap != null)
    {
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
                BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
            Stream pixelStream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
            byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
            await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
        return file;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i already got it. But it seems that MAIL doesn't allow to send images or attachemnts - am i right? Because it only allows me to pick - SkyDriwe

Comment: Mail allows either only attachment or bitmap and/or text.

Comment: Hi man... please, is possible to convert the stream to IStorageItem? (in Javascript please). I want attach this file with others files and therefore use the method setStorageItems :)